# Varnish4 - change PURGE response headers

Tags: caching, http-headers, varnish, varnish-vcl, varnish-4

I'm trying to change PURGE response headers in Varnish4

```
HTTP/1.1 200 Purged
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Fri, 02 Sep 2016 19:57:56 GMT
Retry-After: 5
Server: Varnish
X-Varnish: 163921
Content-Length: 241
Connection: keep-alive
```

I have modified "**Server: Varnish**" in *vcl_recv*, *vcl_deliver*. Which seems to be working with any other request except for PURGE.

I need to change **Server** header or at least add a custom response header

I can't find any documentation about it so I was wondering if anyone done it before or it is a hardcoded option.

Answer (score 2):

You need to override the built-in synthetic response generated by Varnish when purging objects. This can be trivially implemented using some extra VCL:

```
...

sub vcl_purge {
    return (synth(700, "Purged"));
}

sub vcl_synth {
    if (resp.status == 700) {
        set resp.status = 200;
        set resp.http.Server = "ACME";
    }
}
```